Can login using MySQL client (mysql) on Red Hat, but cannot login using mysql shell (mysqlsh) on Windows
So I am having a strange problem.  I have a new MySQL database on AWS RDS (I am not sure if it matters that the database is on RDS vs. on a real machine).  I originally tested with mysql client on a Red Hat (Enterprise Linux) machine, and was able to log into the MySQL database fine.
But then, when I am trying to log into that MySQL database from a Windows machine, where firewalls on the Windows machine are off, I cannot log in successfully.
I installed the MySQL client (from a MSI from MySQL website) on the Windows machine, and I guess now the client that comes with that is "mysqlsh"/MySQL shell, rather than the old/original "mysql" client.
On the Windows machine, I have been trying to log into the MySQL database using the master user, "admin", but when I run the mysqlsh it is failing as follows:
mysqlsh -h xxx-mysql-test.chvinrmx7mvr.1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u admin -p'xxxxxxx'

MySQL Shell 8.0.38

Copyright (c) 2016, 2024, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates.
Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.

Type '\help' or '\?' for help; '\quit' to exit.
WARNING: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Creating a session to 'admin@xxx-mysql-test.chvinrmx7mvr.1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306'
MySQL Error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'xx.yy.1.13' (using password: YES)

I checked the mysql.user table in the database (using the mysql client on RHEL) and I can see that there is a user named "admin" and host is "%".
I tried all kinds of things, like adding an "admin"@IP user in the MySQL, but still cannot log in to it using mysqlsh.
Another strange thing is that I CAN login, using the same "admin" user and password, using the MySQL WorkBench from the same Windows machine!!
So I was wondering if someone might know why I am not able to log in from the Windows machine using "mysqlsh"?
Also, I was wondering:  Is there some way to get/install the older "mysql" client on Windows, instead of the MySQL shell?  Is that still possible?
Thanks, and apologies for the somewhat longish post!!
Jim
EDIT:  FYI, I even installed an older mysql.exe client and tried running the same command line and got the same error on Windows :( !!
EDIT 2:  Per LSerni, I checked the "plugin" attribute and found the following:
MySQL [mysql]> select user,host,plugin from user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user             | host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| admin            | %         | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
| rdsadmin         | localhost | auth_socket           |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+


The most likely possibility seems to me to be a misalignment between the password authentication protocols.
Modern MySQLs use the caching_sha2_password and a SHA hashing, while older servers (and clients) used a proprietary protocol.
Check out the authentication-related values in the mysql.user database.
You can also create test users with a backward compatible authentication algorithm and verify whether that user is allowed to login:
CREATE USER 'adminsha'@'xx.xx.1.13'
IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';

CREATE USER 'adminold'@'xx.xx.1.13'
IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

If this is the cause of the error and you identify a plugin that works, you can modify the access configuration after deleting the test users:
ALTER USER 'admin'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH <whatever_plugin_works> BY 'old-password';


which attributes are the authentication-related values in the mysql.user database ones to look at?

That should be in the plugin column. I suspect that the server will have the native_password installed, while your client is more recent and attempts to use the sha-256 method. This is a situation covered here - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113730

LSerni - sorry took so log - I added the info about plugin and I think you were right.  The admin@% user has "mysql_native_password", but the other users have "caching_sha2_password".  BTW, just remininding that the DB is on AWS RDS.  Also, whatever I do I don't want to mess up/lose access to the "admin" user :(...

LSerni - I tried the test you suggested, making a new 'adminsha'@'xx.xx.1.13' and 'adminold'@'xx.xx.1.13' users, and tested logging into the RDS MySQL DB as both user, using both mysql.exe and mysqlsh.exe on the Windows machine and all the log in attempts failed for both the adminsha and adminold user :( !!!  Now I am really puzzled :( !!

Verify that the test users have the two different plugins in the "plugin" column of mysql.User table, then try changing just the password for both of them. Off the top of my head I'm not completely sure of the plugin-plus-password change syntax; possibly, what I told you to do entered a wrong password for one or both test users. By changing just their passwords, you'll be sure that it is correct.
Also, when you run the tests, keep a window logged as the admin user, and NEVER log out from that. Try logging in admin from a different window to see if it really works.
